# Por que los namespaces funcionan con estas rutas y no con otras? PHP

Tags: php, namespace

Estoy entrando en el tema de los namespaces y ya medio le agarre el hilo, pero me surge una duda y curiosidad, tengo mi carpeta de proyecto, en la raiz principal el index y una carpeta llamada Namespaces, dentro de ella esta un archivo php llamado autoload y una carpeta llamada Prueba y dentro de esa carpeta estan las clases, la ruta estaria asi:

```
Namespaces {
  Prueba {
    clase1.php
    clase2.php
  }    
autoload.php
}


index.php
```

en el index tengo:

```
requiere_once 'Namespaces\autoload.php'
```

y el codigo del autoload es:

```
  spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    include_once str_replace("\\","/",$class) . ".php"; //Me pudieran explicar este codigo? tiene algo que ver con las rutas, pero no entiendo muy bien porque sustituir \\ por /
});
```

ahora con el tema de los namespaces, las clases dentro de la carpeta Prueba, sus namespaces los tengo definidos asi:

```
namespace Namespaces\Prueba;

clase1 {

}

namespace Namespace\Prueba;

clase2 {

}
```

y en el index para usarlos los llamo mediante:

```
use Namespace\Prueba\clase1;
use Namespace\Prueba\clase2;
```

pero si yo en la clase1 el nombre del namespace le pongo:

```
namespace Prueba;
```

y al llamarlo en el index:

```
use Namespace\Prueba\Prueba\prueba;
```

no funciona, por que? no tiene la misma ruta? solo que estaria mas especificado

Comment: Veo que tus preguntas siempre están relacionadas a no saber como/por que funcionan/fallan tus código. Te recomiendo que empieces a usar [`Xdebug`](https://xdebug.org/) para depurar tus códigos. Cuando lo aprendas a usar, programar y entender códigos se te va a volver mas fácil.

Comment: Yo te recomendaría también que le echaras un ojo a composer y usaras su autoload. Te hará la vida más fácil y es un estándar de facto en la comunidad PHP.

Comment: @Marcos veo situaciones igual en al menos el 75% de las preguntas planteadas en el sitio. No sé si actualmente en las facultades/cursos de informática enseñan técnicas de depuración. Es fundamental para un programador aprender a depurar su código. Estaríamos hablando de que te ahorras horas/días/semanas que puedes estar atascado con un problema. Debería haber varias asignaturas dedicadas a la depuración, de modo que todo programador salga con un doctorado en esa materia.

Answer (score 2):

#### Introducción:

`PHP` provee un mecanismo de *auto-carga* de archivos en base al `namespace`.

Cuando se intenta **instanciar una clase que aún no ha sido declarada**, se disparan diversos eventos, entre los cuales estan:

- Verificar si hay una función `autoload` para reescribir el `namespace` a un `path` de archivo (eg: [`spl_autoload_register`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.spl-autoload-register.php)).
- Verificar si el archivo se encuentra dentros de los directorios definidos en [`include_path`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).
- etc.

#### Caso específico:

Cuando se indica que se va a utilizar una clase:

```
use Namespace\Prueba\clase1;
```

o cuando se busca instanciar una clase mediante su `namespace`

```
$obj = new \Namespace\Prueba\clase1;
```

Y dicha clase no a sido declarada aún, `PHP` pone en acción el mecanismo de `autoload`, el cual ejecuta todas las funciones registradas para, valga la redundancia, cargar automáticamente el archivo `.php` donde esta declarada dicha clase.

Si analizamos paso a paso tu función de `autoload`:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    include_once str_replace("\\","/",$class) . ".php"; //Me pudieran explicar este codigo? tiene algo que ver con las rutas, pero no entiendo muy bien porque sustituir \\ por /
});
```

Vemos que:

- La variable `$class` será igual a la cadena `Namespace\Prueba\clase1`
- Luego al ejecutar `str_replace("\\","/",$class)` será igual a `Namespace/Prueba/clase1`
- Luego se concatena `"Namespace/Prueba/clase1" . ".php"`, por lo que resultará en `Namespace/Prueba/clase1.php`
- Finalmente quedará evaluar `include_once 'Namespace/Prueba/clase1.php';`

A partir de aquí es donde entra en acción el mecanismos de `include_path`, que si bien puede parecer que escapa al scope de la pregunta, no es así (*planto la semilla* `;)`)

#### Conclusión:

Cuando utilizas `use Namespace\Prueba\Prueba\prueba;` no funciona, porque:

- Al aplicar la función de `autoload` se intenta incluir el archivo `Namespace/Prueba/Prueba/prueba.php`
- Y al recorrer los `include_path` no se encuentra.
- Falla.

Comment: cuál es la diferencia entre Namespaces/Prueba/clase1 y Namespace\Prueba\clase1?

Comment: No lo tomes a mal, pero realmente no entiendo por que la pregunta. Si es por sintaxis de `PHP` la primera es inválida y la otra no (`namespace`). Si es por sintaxis de ruta de directorio, en `Linux` una funciona y la otra no; en `Windows` ambas funcionan, pero pero la primera es reescrita automáticamente a la segunda. Si es por comparar cadenas, una tiene barras `/` y la otra tiene barras hacia atras `\\`